# Efficient way to find unique numpy arrays from a large set having the same shape and dtype

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have a large set (~ 10000) of `numpy` arrays,  (a1, a2, a3,...,a10000).  Each array has the same shape (10, 12) and all are of `dtype` = int.   In any row of any array, the 12 values are unique.

Now, there are many doubles, triples, etc.  I suspect only about a tenth of the arrays are actually unique (ie: having the same values in the same positions).

Could I get some advice on how I might isolate the unique arrays?  I suspect `numpy.array_equal` will be involved, but I'm new enough to the language that I'm struggling with how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) can be used to find the unique elements of an array. Supposing your data is contained in a list; first, stack data to generate a 3D array. Then perform `np.unique` to find unique 2D arrays:

```
import numpy as np

#  dummy list of numpy array to simulate your data
list_of_arrays = [np.stack([np.random.permutation(12) for i in range(10)]) for i in range(10000)]

#  stack arrays to form a 3D array
arr = np.stack(list_of_arrays) 

#  find unique arrays
unq = np.unique(arr, axis = 0)
```

Comment: Excellent response!  Very fast.